# Is possible to use abstract class in xml serialization when using XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-parsing

**Question**
When I'm using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` with classes decorated with the `System.Xml.Serialization` attributes (e.g. `XmlRoot`, `XmlElement`, ...) can I create a property in some of the classes with type as a abstract class?

**Scenario**
I have these classes:

```
[XmlRoot("autor")]
public class Author
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("books")]
    [XmlArrayItem("book")]
    public List<Book> Livros { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("info")]
    public ExtraData ExtraData { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("year")]
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ExtraData
{
}

public class ExtraDataTest : ExtraData
{
    [XmlElement("test")]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

And I try this snippet:

```
var author = new Author
{
    Name = "George R. R. Martin",
    Livros = new List<Book>
    {
        new Book { Name = "A Game of Thrones", Year = 1996 },
        new Book { Name = "The Hedge Knight", Year = 1998 },
    },
    // ExtraData = new ExtraDataTest { Test = "Some Info" }
    // See the comment below to know why this line was commented.
};

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Author));

using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
using(var sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
using(var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
{
    var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("","");
    serializer.Serialize(sw, author, ns);

    sw.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    sr.ReadToEnd().Dump(); // Dump is a extended method of LinqPad
}
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<autor>
  <name>George R. R. Martin</name>
  <books>
    <book>
      <name>A Game of Thrones</name>
      <year>1996</year>
    </book>
    <book>
      <name>The Hedge Knight</name>
      <year>1998</year>
    </book>
  </books>
</autor>
```

**Problem**
So if I uncomment the line that set the `ExtraData` property one exception is throw when I try to serialize the object:

> `System.ObjectDisposedException`
>   Cannot access a closed Stream.

So this is why I'm asking if it possible, if yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible.

The only thing missing that I see from your code is to use the [XmlInclude attrubute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  on your abstract class to inform the serializer that it should look for derived classes like this:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(ExtraDataTest))]
public abstract class ExtraData
{
}
```